# How to Push VC from UISearchController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I have set up a UISearchController like so:

```
SearchTableViewController *searchView = [[SearchTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SearchTableViewController" bundle:nil];
UISearchController *searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:searchView];
[searchController setDefinesPresentationContext:YES];
searchController.delegate = searchView;
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchView;
[self presentViewController:searchController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When I am trying to push something from the search controller like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
DetailTableViewController *seeAll = (DetailTableViewController *) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailTableViewController"];
 NSLog(@"self.navigationController = %@", self.navigationController);
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:seeAll animated:YES];
```

it doesn't work. I get null printed out as a result of the NSLog. Can anyone help please?

This is my IB File [image]

Answer (score 0):

You get null printed out as a result due to absence of navigation stack for `self`(SearchTableViewController). It seems like don't specify UINavigationController in your storyboard. What is your main.storyboard file? One of possible configurations using storyboard looks like this:

[image]

Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html) example from Apple. It has similar functionality. 
P.S. I'm not sure you need present SearchController like this:

```
[self presentViewController:searchController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Ok well my view hierarchy is kind of wanky so be prepared. I have a Navigation controller and a VC as shown above, except, the VC has a segmented control which loads two views like so `self.asd = [[asd alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:self.asd.view];` Then this VC loads three more Xibs

Comment: @MarkBourke could you clarify where do you executing first peace of code listed in your question? Maybe you can add more code in order I'll be able to understand context? 
What will be logged if you put this code:
 `NSLog(@"self.navigationController = %@", self.navigationController);` in place where you create UISearchController?

Comment: Result of Log : self.navigationController = <NavigationController: 0x7fcc5d050000>

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate your searchController with another NavigationController

```
    SearchTableViewController *searchView = [[SearchTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SearchTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    UISearchController *searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:searchView];
    [searchController setDefinesPresentationContext:YES];
    searchController.delegate = searchView;
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchView;
UINavitagionController * navCont = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController: searchController];
    [self presentViewController:navCont animated:YES completion:nil];
```